# Kotlin activity crash

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi am trying to make a multi-activity app and it is working fine with 2 activities but when i am adding a 3rd activity it is redirecting back to main activity and 2nd time the app is crashing.
In logcat it is showing that the error is in the last activity super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
function. When i am removing setContentView(R.layout.activity_adminactivity) line which is below the oncreate function then a empty activity is opening although i have made a xml for that page.

Error:

`at com.example.blockchainproductidentification.AdminActivity.onCreate(AdminActivity.kt:13)`

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question (that's why I'm posting this as a comment), but creating applications with multiple activities isn't really encouraged anymore, it is easier to just use multiple fragments and one activity

Comment: please share the complete crash log.

Answer (score -1):

If you add third activity manually, could you check that did you add these lines on manifest->

```
<activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
```